# How i do autofocus in a html form

Tags: html, forms

This is my structure but doesn't works

```html
<form>
  <label for="some_name">Message</label>
  <input id="some_name" type="text" name="some_name" value="Some Value" autofocus/>
</form>
```

Comment: Works fine in snippet

Comment: [are you using a browser that doesn't support autofocus?](http://caniuse.com/#search=autofocus)

Answer (score 1):

I tested it in both Chrome and Firefox. Chrome seems to work fine, but Firefox doesn't.

According to [this](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/15020/why-doesnt-autofocus-autofocus-work-in-mozilla-firefox) post Firefox 4 should support it. It also states that you should have a fallback for browsers that do not support it.

*Answer from [Nick](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/15020/why-doesnt-autofocus-autofocus-work-in-mozilla-firefox#answer-15023):*

It's wise to use `autofocus` with a JavaScript fallback for browsers that don't support it. From Mark Pilgrim's [Dive into HTML5 Forms](http://diveintohtml5.org/forms.html):

> What’s that? You say you want your autofocus fields to work in all browsers, not just these fancy-pants HTML5 browsers? You can keep your current autofocus script. Just make two small changes:
>
> Add the autofocus attribute to your HTML markup Detect whether the
>   browser supports the autofocus attribute, and only run your own
>   autofocus script if the browser doesn’t support autofocus natively.

```
<form name="f">
  <input id="q" type="text" name="Gw" maxlength="225" size="42" autofocus>
  <script>
    if (!("autofocus" in document.createElement("input"))) {
      document.getElementById("q").focus();
    }
  </script>
  <input type="submit" value="Go">
</form>
```

[Live demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/rhWpc/)